# How can an isolated system filled upto the brim with some fluid get more random?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

This is probably stupid, but like an isolated tank which is completely filled with some liquid or stuff can't have any more entropy on its own right?

Comment: What if you add heat to the liquid?

Comment: What I meant to ask was if the system can't interact with the outside in any way will it still obey the second law of thermodynamics and get more 'random' or disordered in any way?